# Adding or Displaying Site Actions Gear Icon Using Custom SharePoint Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am using a custom Master Page within my SharePoint Site in SharePoint 2013 Site.

In the top right corner the Gear Icon is not displaying. But when I hover on it the place holder work and when I click on it the menu is displaying correctly.

Now I want it to display that gear icon using my custom master page.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by my self. The reason was to hidden the gear icon was styling. I had accidentally modified CORE15.css file that resides within the themed folder.

So I replace it with an unedited file and then after the problem was solved.